# Can you play music from earphones AND speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, headphones, speakers

I wanted to play music in background for people in room,
while listening to other things on headphones.

I tried to have different devices play for different windows,
but as soon as i plug my headphones in my laptop speakers are
no longer available in neither sound setting nor in pulse audio app.
I also tried to boost volume with alsamixer, but with no success.

I am using 18.04 on HP OMEN laptop.

EDIT:
I can use bluetooth headphones for this, they are recoginsed as separate audio output, but wired headphones are recognised as a built-in audio.

Comment: Have you sufficiently gone thorough all of the system settings?  Particularly your sound settings: `Add virtual output device for simultaneous output on all local sound cards`

Comment: it is on, problem is that it seems that both headphones and laptop speakers are recognized as built-in audio, and i can't target only one

Comment: The point of the virtual device is that you choose that as your output and audio is mirrored across all devices. FYI, I am fairly certain that you can't play one source audio to one output and a totally different source audio to a different output.

Comment: You can, if i connect my bluetooth headphones i can play different thing on them and on speakers, but can't do the same with wired headphones.